# EF Code First - Define Two-Way Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this entity class

```
public class Node
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Node Prev { get; set; }
    public virtual Node Next { get; set; }
}
```

A node will always have 0 or 1 previous node and 0 or 1 next node.

And I would like EF to generate the following table schema

```
Id | Name | Prev_Id | Next_Id
```

As you will soon notice that, `Next_Id` is redundant since `Prev_Id` is sufficient to define the directional relationship.

My purpose of this table schema is to efficiently query whether a node has a previous / next node without doing a join operation on its own table. And I am happy to take the trade-off that I have to write extra logic to maintain the prev/next id correctness.

**Here is my problem:**

The EF fails to create such table with the following error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Node' and 'Node'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

I wonder if EF allows such design and how.

## UPDATES

I change to this and still got the same error

```
public class Node
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PrevId { get; set; }
    public int NextId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PrevId")]
    public virtual Node Prev { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("NextId")]
    public virtual Node Next { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: see this link http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @FrebinFrancis I tried to follow the instructions with the following design:

    public class Node
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int PrevId { get; set; }
        public int NextId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PrevId")]
        public virtual Node Prev { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("NextId")]
        public virtual Node Next { get; set; }
    }

yet i still got the same error.

Comment: Can you please show me the code ? Please update it in your question ?

Comment: try to use [InverseProperty] data annotation attribute In that link Not Foreign Key attribute

Comment: @FrebinFrancis If I replace with `[InverseProperty("PrevId")]` I will get: The property 'PrevId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. Consider re-design your table schema. Let's say I want to add 3 new nodes like following:

```
var first = new Node { Name = "first" };
var second = new Node { Name = "second" };
var third = new Node { Name = "third" };

first.Next = second;
second.Prev = first;
second.Next = third;
third.Prev = second;

---- expected table data ----
Id       Name         PrevId        NextId
1        first         NULL           2
2        second         1             3
3        third          2            NULL
```

Now you tell me which row should be inserted first. If the id=1 row is inserted first, it breaks the foreign key constraint because NextId=2 doesn't exist. Similarly id=2 & id=3 rows can't be inserted first.

Maybe you can remove the foreign key constraint and manage the relationship by yourself in the code, or using store procedures.

Comment: In this case I will first insert three nodes without specifying the relations, then update them in the second round.

Comment: @SiuPangTommyChoi That's correct. You realized that it can't be done in a single insert. That's why I say "manage the relationship by yourself", because EF is not smart enough to know "insert first, update later".

Comment: Agreed, I don't expect EF to check data integrity. Do you think I can still use the navigational properties anyway?

Comment: @SiuPangTommyChoi I don't think you should continue using navigation properties. Maybe change it to a normal property, and manage its value in your middle tier code. BTW I think you can keep `Prev_id` foreign key and remove `Next_id`(or keep next and remove prev). Don't remove both.